# Java persist operation causes everytime a rollback in the MySQL DB

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, rollback, persist

I have a problem.

I have this function:

```
public boolean insertOrgToAlign(OrganizationData orgData) {
        try {
            if (eManager.find(ScOrgNotAligned.class, orgData.getOrganizationCode()) == null) {
                ScAdminGroup rootByOrg = null;
                AdminGroupBean admGrp = null;
                try {
                    rootByOrg = adminGroupServices.getRootAdminGroupByOrg(orgData.getOrganizationCode());
                } catch (NoResultException e) {
                    logger.debugT("insertOrgToAlign(..) - org to align has no root");
                    return false;
                } catch (NonUniqueResultException e) {
                    logger.debugT("insertOrgToAlign(..) - org to align has more than one root");
                    admGrp = new AdminGroupBean();
                    admGrp.setAdmGroupId(-1);
                    admGrp.setAdmGroupName("ERROR");
                    ScOrgNotAligned scOrgNotAlig = new ScOrgNotAligned(orgData, admGrp);
                    eManager.persist(scOrgNotAlig);
                    logger.debugT("insertOrgToAlign(..) - persist org to adjust manually : "
                            + orgData.getOrganizationName());
                    return true;
                }
                admGrp = new AdminGroupBean(rootByOrg);
                ScOrgNotAligned scOrgNotAlig = new ScOrgNotAligned(orgData, admGrp);
                //**************************
                //THIS IS THE WRONG LINE????
                eManager.persist(scOrgNotAlig);
                //**************************
                logger.debugT("insertOrgToAlign(..) - persist org to align : " + orgData.getOrganizationName());
            } else {
                logger.debugT("insertOrgToAlign(..) - org to align already exists in db : "
                        + orgData.getOrganizationName());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.traceThrowableT(Severity.ERROR, e.getMessage(), e);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

If I comment the **eManager.persist(scOrgNotAlig);** line, the function write right in the DB; if I uncomment the line, the function causes a rollback at the time it go to write in the DB.

The stacktrace of the exception is:

```
(Failed in component: sap.com/tc~ejbexplorer~ear, BC-JAS-EJB) nested exception is: 
com.sap.engine.services.ts.exceptions.BaseRollbackException: Exception in
beforeCompletion of ( JTA Transaction : 45491 ).
```

Why? Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show us the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: I add to the queestion ;)

Comment: Well, that does not seem the (entire) stack trace... if that is all that you get, I does not help much...

Comment: In the stacktrace I don't have an exception! This is the strange thing.... I only obtain this in the EJB explorer page...